# Find the largest integer value for a specific entry in an array of indentical hashes

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a data structure such as this:

```
[[{:value=>"First Item", :value_length=>10, :index=>0},
  {:value=>"1111", :value_length=>4, :array_index=>1}],
 [{:value=>"Second Item", :value_length=>11, :index=>0},
  {:value=>"2222", :value_length=>4, :array_index=>1}],
 [{:value=>"Third Item", :value_length=>10, :index=>0},
  {:value=>"3333", :value_length=>4, :index=>1}],
 [{:value=>"Fourth Item", :value_length=>11, :index=>0},
  {:value=>"4444", :value_length=>4, :index=>1}]]
```

(console output)

How could I get the largest **:value_length** in the array?

Comment: I just haven't got very far..elaborate loops and things that simply don't cut it :/

Comment: It's expected that you will show us the code you've tried. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: I do understand..I do that when I can, but seriously it wouldn't have helped

Comment: `a.flatten.map(&:to_a).flatten.select {|e| e.is_a? String}.map(&:size).max` works.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
your_array.flatten.map{|h| h[:value_length]}.max
# => 11
```

Comment: Darn it you beat me too it :)

Comment: @jozefg Do you do Ruby too? :)

Comment: I do :) Scripting in Haskell isn't nearly as fun

Comment: Protip: When you are using a flatten and a map back to back it is often better to use the flat_map enumerable method. However, you may run into problems when you are dealing with deeply nested data structures.

Comment: @demondeac11 Would you show me how `flat_map` can be used in this case?

Comment: @demondeac11 Have you looked at my previous comment? Can you show me how `flat_map` can be used in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I was sad because @sawa was faster. But I will still answer in case you want to get the full hash.

```
your_array.flatten.max {|x, y| x[:value_length] <=> y[:value_length] }
#=> {:value=>"Second Item", :value_length=>11, :index=>0}
```

Comment: @sawa has one of those quick-draw holsters.

Comment: I actually use good keyboards. I usually use HHKB Professional 2. Recently, I use Filco Majestouch.